# How to make "tab" trigger the auto-complete suggestions in VSCode only when there is text before it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I basically want to figure out a way for the the tab button in VSCode to behave like it does in RStudio. In RStudio, it does two different things depending on the context; it inserts a tab character if there is no text before the cursor on the current line and it shows the auto-complete suggestions if there is text before the cursor on the current line.
As an example:

If my cursor is here, the tab button should insert a tab character.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
^here
```

However, if its here, it should bring up the auto-complete suggestions window.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
         ^here
```

I looked in the "when clause contexts" of VSCode, but didn't find any I could use to help me solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've got no solution for the problem, but when would you ever need a tab character in Python code since according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) indentation should be done with spaces?

Comment: You make a good point, however, python is just an example language I used for the question. The question itself applies to any language you can edit in VSCode.

Comment: Then I hope someone can and will answer your question.